# How do I remove separate elements in a vector without using the range function?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I've created vector x and I need to create a vector z by removing the 3rd and 6th elements of x. I cannot just create a vector by simply typing in the elements that should be in z. I have to index them or use a separate function.

```
x = [5,2,0,6,-10,12]
np.array(x)
print x

z = np.delete(x,)
```

I am not sure if using np.delete is best or if there is a better approach. Help?

Comment: have you tried `np.delete`? look up the numpy.delete documentation and find some examples to follow. you're nearly there. one thing to get used to with python is there are *tons* of ways to approach every problem. so you do need to pick one and follow through until you've gotten to know it. sure, there are more efficient ways to do anything, but you're off to a fine start.

Comment: Just search a bit and [read the documnetation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding)…

Comment: fwiw, your approach (if completed) would be faster than @I'mahdi's answer using list comprehension :)

Comment: also - `print x` is python 2 syntax which won't work with modern python (we're now up to 3.11). so if you're following an old book or something you'll have to learn to update the syntax to python 3 unfortunately. you'll need to call print like a function, i.e. `print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can index and conact pieces of the list excluding the one you want to "delete"

```
x = [5,2,0,6,-10,12]
print ( x[0:2]+x[3:5] )

[5, 2, 6, -10]
```

Answer (score 0):

if x is numpy array, first convert to list:

`x = list(x)`

if not array then:

```py
z = [x.pop(2), x.pop(-1)]
```

This will remove 3rd and 6th element form x and place it in z. Then convert it to numpy array if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [69]: x = np.array([5,2,0,6,-10,12])
```

Using `delete` is straight forward:

```
In [70]: np.delete(x,[2,5])
Out[70]: array([  5,   2,   6, -10])
```

`delete` is a general function that takes various approaches based on the delete object, but in a case like this it uses a boolean mask:

```
In [71]: mask = np.ones(x.shape, bool); mask[[2,5]] = False; mask
Out[71]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False])    
In [72]: x[mask]
Out[72]: array([  5,   2,   6, -10])
```